# Set maximum audio volume on macOS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I cannot recall precisely, but while attempting to type "9" or "0" or hit the Delete key or other keys in that area of the top row, I just fat-fingered my headphone volume to maximum on the touch bar. It greatly startled me and caused me to shout out loud at work.

I love using the touch bar. I am never going to improve my clumsy hand movements. I require constant headphones at work to concentrate. I need my headphones plugging into my laptop so I can hear the occasional audio cue from other apps.

However, I absolutely cannot let this happen again. I scared all my nearby teammates with my sudden loud shout. I had to assure them it was OK, explain what happened, and apologize for the disturbance.

I recalled my iPod shuffle has a feature to limit the maximum volume on it, and I figured an even more feature-full OS would surely also have that feature, but I cannot seem to find it in System Preferences.

Am I missing the feature? Is there a Terminal command I can type that limits the maximum volume to a lower level?

Comment: I had a similar experience after leaning on my headphone's volume control and pressing play. I made a small status bar app which allows you to set a volume limit: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whisper-volume-limiter/id1438132944

Comment: @odlp I think your comment can be a full fledged answer, if you are interested in gaining SE points and better marketing for your app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're still on the hunt for such an application, I have great news. I wrote a simple status menu bar app, which lets you limit the main output volume of your Mac. The app is called [Earsafe](https://earsafe.io), check it out if you have time.

All the best!

Comment: Can you set a limit in decibels? I don't really understand what "40%" means in terms of limit.

Comment: You can't set the limit in decibels, unfortunately. 
When you set the volume on your Mac, you set it to a certain percentage value (0.37 or 0.4). It's only displayed in the sound settings for end-users. Basically, my app sets your volume to a certain limit (which you can set through its menu) everytime your current volume exceeds that value.

Comment: I love it! Does this also answer [Audio output limiter for Mac? NOT volume control](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/138650/143729)

Comment: Yes, it does! It basically limits the currently selected output on your Mac.

Comment: Please can you update it for Catalina? Since I updated my MacBook, I have to restart Earsafe everytime I use my computer after it was put in sleep mode.

Comment: I've started working on the Catalina update. There are a lots of things I should relearn now because of it, so please bear with me! :)

Comment: Earsafe v2 is out. You can find out what's new in it at [earsafe.io](https://earsafe.io).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and it was solved (not intentionally, just a happy by-product) by using a 3rd party media player.

In my case, I used [Vox](https://vox.rocks/).  It has it's own volume control which I set at a level that no matter if the system is set to "max" it won't be any louder than what is set in the app.

[image]

The best part is Vox is free (as in beer).

Comment: iTunes can do this as well. Its volume is independent of the system one.

Comment: @seaturtle - True...iTunes is just a horrible interface, so there's that.

Comment: I find iTunes quite nice, but I'm keeping a slightly older version around (v12.3.2.35) because I don't like the newer changes. (:

Answer (score 2):

So this solves my clumsy typing problem, but it does not answer my question of limiting maximum audio volume.

I went into *System Preferences > Keyboard* and tapped the "Customize Control Strip..." button. From there I dragged the volume slider from my touch bar to the "Remove from touch bar" area.

Now I have greatly reduced my chance of accidentally engaging that control and then inadvertantly swiping right dramatically. And now that I think about it, I'll remove Siri from a nearby spot also.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience after leaning on my headphone's volume control and pressing play. I made a small status bar app which allows you to set a volume limit: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whisper-volume-limiter/id1438132944